# Как сравнить даты в формате String

Tags: php

Здравстуйте, у меня есть дата в формате String, как мне определить, что прошло уже больше 4х секунд?

Строка с датой выглядит так: 09.04.2017 18:09:17

Мне нужно сравнить ее с текущей датой, но проверить, прошло ли больше 4х секунд, если да, то получить return "yes";, если еще 4 секунды не прошло, то return "no".

Как это сделать?

Comment: с текущей датой где? на сервере? в приложении? у клиента? в зависимости от часового пояса? не смотря на то, что часы у одной из сторон могут спешить/отставать? не смотря на то, что могут часы быть вообще переведены?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php) понимает этот формат, поэтому можно просто использовать его:

```
$datetime = '09.04.2017 18:09:17';
if(time() - strtotime($datetime) > 4) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: а если он дату принимает от апи? А сравнивает со своим временем на сервере? хм....

Comment: Я просто ответил на поставленный вопрос. Понятно, что задача поставлена не вполне точно. Надеюсь, что дата была получена в этом же скрипте)

Comment: ох, это всё может плохо кончиться...))

Comment: @vp_arth дата от сервера, все нормально) Спасибо